# Binding html text to innerHTML inside a template

Tags: winjs

I have a flipview which references a Template. Inside the template I would like to set the innerHTML property on a div. My datasource backed by an indexeddb database. The data source consists of html fragments which are then populated in the flipview via the innerHTML property.

```
<div id="simple_ItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
```

```
    <div id="simple_FlipView" style="display:none;" class="flipView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.FlipView"
        data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: ReaderStoryList.datasource, itemTemplate: select('#simple_ItemTemplate') }">
    </div>
```

This was working fine until I started adding 3d transforms in the html fragments. Now I get the error:

Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic contet...

What I want to do is apply MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction around the binding of the template. Is this possible? Or is there any other way I can workaround this error?

Comment: You can try [WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe()] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211696.aspx) but it does not seem to work on my sample code.

Comment: Are you using a library for the 3d transforms? This has been a problem for other libraries, e.g. jQuery had to get forked and it took some time to get it compatible with the WinRT way of doing things, i.e. no inserting scripts into the DOM. It might be there's another library that's more compatible than the one you're using.